# Preserve field data when copying files between SharePoint libraries

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, data-migration

I am trying to write a script that copies files from one SharePoint library to another in the same site.
Some fields like creator, modified by and last modified should be preserved, if possible all fields.

So far I have come up with the following:

```
$items = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl "OldLibrary" -ItemType File 
foreach($item in $items) {
    #This is a workaround, because there is a bug in Copy-PnPFile
    $item.CopyTo("NewLibrary/$($item.Name)", $true)                   
}
Invoke-PnPQuery

foreach($item in $items) {                                
     $oldItem = Get-PnPFile -Url $item.ServerRelativeUrl -AsListItem
     $newItem = Get-PnpFile -Url "NewLibrary/$($item.Name)" -AsListItem

     Set-PnPListItem -List "NewLibrary" -Identity $newItem.Id -Values @{"Last_x0020_Modified" = $oldItem["Last_x0020_Modified"]; "Author" = $oldItem["Author"]; "Editor" = $oldItem["Editor"]}

}
```

The copy works fine.
But the fields are not preserved. Creation date, author and modified by date show the current time and the user who executed the copy script.

I get an error message: "Set-PnPListItem: Input string was not in a correct format"

How can I preserve the fields? Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

The error was that I updated the wrong field.
Instead of "Last_x0020_Modified" I needed to update the "Modified" field. Additionally, the author and editor field needed the email address.

The solution looks like this now and works fine.

```
Set-PnPListItem -List "NewLibrary" -Identity $newItem.Id -Values @{"Modified" = $oldItem["Modified"]; "Author" = $oldItem["Author"].Email; "Editor" = $oldItem["Editor"].Email}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is simple. All we need to know is that when a file is copied in SharePoint, a new id and other information such as modified by and created date are given to the file by SharePoint.

But when you move a file from one location to another, these pieces of information are not changed rather they are maintained. So as a software Developer my advice is to use the `MOVETO()` method in `CSOM` rather than using the server binary `direct()` method which copies a file to a new location.